# Handling slow requests in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, graphql

For a single request, we can monitor its response time by using consol.log(start) at the beginning of request and console.log(end) at the point where the response is sent.
I want in the event that any request to API hangs for a long period (greater than 5-10s), I should be able to terminate the request, return an error, and log both the request and the stack trace.
How can I be able to do it at the app-level rather than for adding this console.log for each request?

On the server, I do have Nginx.

Comment: middleware [koa](https://github.com/js-fullstack/koa-timeout-v2) [express](https://github.com/expressjs/timeout)

Comment: oh.. be aware that this doesn't stop the actual code from running, just sends a response to the client

Comment: Yes but i want to abort the request something we can do at nginx level? @Matt

Comment: Can't do more in nginx than the middleware does.

Comment: “Implement a failsafe for slow requests NodeJs” by Aryan kanwar https://medium.com/@kanwararyan1/implement-a-failsafe-for-slow-requests-nodejs-3a5167f3fbb5